# Выполнить действия с данными ячеек в QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer, qtablewidget

Во второй вкладке у меня есть таблица `QTableWidget`, и вот я пытался сделать чтобы данные из колонок 2 и 5 складывались и из них вычиталась льгота. 
Помогите пожалуйста напишите как мне сделать выше упомянутые операции.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from food import Ui_MainWindow      
                                    
                                    
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, rows):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.rows = rows
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set_row_count)
        self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed)         

    def set_row_count(self):
        self.rows += 1
        print(self.rows)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.rows)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(self.rows)

    def cell_changed(self, row, column):
        _sum = 0
        if 1 < column < 7:
            for column in range(2, 7):
                if self.tableWidget.item(row, column) != None:
                    try:
                        _sum +=  int(self.tableWidget.item(row, column).text())
                    except:
                        pass

            _bud = 0
            if self.tableWidget.item(row, 1) != None:
                _bud = int(self.tableWidget.item(row, 1).text())
            ost = _bud - _sum            
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 7, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(ost)))


number_rows = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow(number_rows)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**food.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(995, 620)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    font-size:14px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QWidget {\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 981, 581))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.tab)
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 20, 110, 22))
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:gray;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 961, 491))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(8)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText("Имя ученика")
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, item)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tableWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 10, 721, 521))
        self.tableWidget_2.setObjectName("tableWidget_2")
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(7)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText("Имя ученика")
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 995, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить ученика"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Бюджет"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пн"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ср"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Чт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(7)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Остаток"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Бюджет"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Хлеб"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Булочка"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Горячее"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Напиток"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Льгота"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сумма"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Питание"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Укажите более точный вопрос, отлаживать это никто не будет за вас. Укажите конкретно где и что не работает или работает неверною.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Старайтесь вникать в текст, который вам пишут. Т.к. то что вы спрашиваете я вам уже писал, смотрите метод выше добавленного мной.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from food import Ui_MainWindow      


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, rows):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.rows = rows
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set_row_count)
        self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed)    

        self.tableWidget_2.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed_2)         


    def set_row_count(self):
        self.rows += 1
        print(self.rows)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.rows)

        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(self.rows)                    # <<<-----<

    def cell_changed(self, row, column):
        _sum = 0
        if 1 < column < 7:
            for column in range(2, 7):
                if self.tableWidget.item(row, column) != None:
                    try:
                        _sum +=  int(self.tableWidget.item(row, column).text())
                    except:
                        pass

            _bud = 0
            if self.tableWidget.item(row, 1) != None:
                _bud = int(self.tableWidget.item(row, 1).text())
            ost = _bud - _sum            
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 7, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(ost)))



### vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
    def cell_changed_2(self, row, column):
        _sum = 0
        if 0 < column < 6:
            for column in range(1, 5):
                if self.tableWidget_2.item(row, column) != None:
                    try:
                        _sum +=  int(self.tableWidget_2.item(row, column).text())
                    except:
                        pass

            _lgota = 0

            if self.tableWidget_2.item(row, 5) != None :
                _lgota = int(self.tableWidget_2.item(row, 5).text())

            ost = _sum - _lgota

            self.tableWidget_2.setItem(row, 6, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(ost)))

### ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


number_rows = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow(number_rows)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я пытался делать по тому что вы писали раньше у меня неполучилось поэтому я задал вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!